# MongoDB query: all documents that contain reference to a specific id

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to extract some data from a legacy mongo db (v. 2.0.4). I have data that is structured like this:

```json
{"_id": "1",
 "@graph": {"ma:isMemberOf": [{"@id": "524224b804743b02a4c23488",
                               "title": "IHum 350",
                               "transcript": "False"},
                              {"@id": "53cfd59404743bc3c9119adf",
                               "restrictor": "578e89ae04743b7b0816beff",
                               "title": "Spanish 339",
                               "transcript": "False"}],
            "ma:title": "Toy title 1"},
"_id": "2",
 "@graph": {"ma:isMemberOf": [{"@id": "524224b804743b02a4c23488",
                               "title": "IHum 350",
                               "transcript": "False"}],
            "ma:title": "Toy title 2"}}
```

...and I want to write a query that will find all of the documents that are members of a particular group (matching the `@id` field). For example, I want to be able to search for `524224b804743b02a4c23488` and receive documents 1 and 2. Or to search for `53cfd59404743bc3c9119adf` and receive only document 1.

I have tried several things, but I can't figure out how to query embedded objects.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
db.collection.find({
  "@graph.ma:isMemberOf.@id": <your query>
})
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ULsBd7NWbu9) for your reference.

Comment: `{"@graph.ma:isMemberOf.@id": "524224b804743b02a4c23488"}` will suffice.  There is no need for $elemMatch.

Comment: Doing it with `$elemMatch` did not work for me, but just querying directly as @AlexBlex  wrote in the above comment works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexBlex Thanks for your advice and I have updated the answer accordingly.